# how to round decimal values in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

How do I round a formula result decimal value from 28.234 to 28.24 in crystal reports.

I am only getting 28.23 when I set the decimal to .00.

The field is formatted as a custom field: (decimal = 1.00 and rounding = 0.01).

Using Crystal Reports Version 2013.

Comment: I have formatted the Field to custom (Decimal 1.00, Rounding 0.01)

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula and use the `RoundUp`-function:

```
RoundUp(28.234, 2)
```